# Find All IDs with that have both categories and calculate time difference

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have a pandas dataframe that looks something like this:

| ID | Category | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 1/1/22 10:14:12 AM |
| 1 | A | 1/1/22 10:12:12 AM |
| 1 | B | 1/2/22 10:14:12 AM |
| 2 | A | 1/1/22 10:14:12 AM |
| 3 | A | 1/2/22 10:14:12 AM |
| 3 | B | 1/1/22 10:14:12 AM |
| 3 | B | 1/1/22 10:18:12 AM |

What I want is to get only the IDs that have category A and category B. Then, I want to calculate the absolute (value) time difference between their respective two dates (in hours). The ideal result would look something like:

| ID | Time Difference |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 24 |
| 3 | 24 |

EDIT: Let me try to clarify a few things. There can be duplicate ID/Category for each combination. For example, ID 1 and Category A can exist a few times. The date/time stamp will be different for those situations, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is one way to do it

```
# convert the date to datetime (unless its already datetime)
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])

# sort and drop duplicates, keeping latest
df=df.sort_values(['ID', 'Category','Date']).drop_duplicates(subset=['ID','Category','Date'], keep='last')

# pivot to put 'A' and 'B' as two columns
df2=df.pivot(index='ID', columns='Category', values='Date').reset_index()

# eliminate the rows where either of the two column (dates) are null
df2.dropna(inplace=True)



# this to get rid of spaces from Category, unless its already stripped of whitespaces characters
df2.columns = [col.strip() for col in df2.columns]


# calculate the difference
df2['time_difference']= df2['A'].sub(df2['B']).dt.total_seconds()/3600
df2
```

```
ID  A   B   time_difference
0   1   2022-01-01 10:14:12     2022-01-02 10:14:12     -24.0
2   3   2022-01-02 10:14:12     2022-01-01 10:14:12     24.0
```

Comment: I get an error with this approach. ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape

Comment: Still receiving the same error as before.

Comment: sorry about that, do a dropna right after the drop_duplicates. it should help. It'll be much easier if I can reproduce it

Comment: i updated the solution as well

Comment: Sorry, not sure what is going on. With updated code it is still giving me the same issue.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248609/discussion-between-naveed-and-robert-calimente).

Comment: I dropped the 'date' out of .dropduplicates(subset()) and it ended up working. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Using [.groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) [.diff](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.diff.html) [.assign](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html)

```
df["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Date"])
df = df.sort_values(["ID", "Date"], ascending=[1, 1])
df = (
    df
    .assign(DeltaHours=df.groupby(["ID"]).Date.diff().dt.days * 24)
    .dropna()
    .reset_index(drop=True)[["ID", "DeltaHours"]]
)
print(df)

   ID  DeltaHours
1   1  24.0
3   3  24.0
```

Comment: I get an error with this approach. 'AttributeError: 'DataFrameGroupBy' object has no attribute 'date''

Comment: Your column name is Date not date. Edited

Comment: When making that change, I get this error. TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'float' and 'datetime.datetime'

Comment: Your date column isn't a date, Edited

Comment: I had already used pd.to_datetime to convert the column to date and it was giving me that error.

Comment: Does the full data have a NaN or Nat in the Date column?

Comment: Yes it's possible to have NaN

Comment: Hmm well I tested with np.NaN, pd.NaT, "", and None and didn't have that issue.

Answer (score 0):

Using a `pivot`:

```
out = (df
   .assign(Date=pd.to_datetime(df['Date']))
   .pivot_table(index='ID', columns='Category', values='Date', aggfunc='max')
   .pipe(lambda d: d['A'].sub(d['B']).abs().dt.total_seconds().div(3600))
   .dropna()
   .reset_index(name='Time Difference')
 )
```

Output:

```
   ID  Time Difference
0   1             24.0
1   3             24.0
```

Comment: I get an error with this approach. ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape

Comment: @Robert do you have multiple A/B per ID? How do you want to handle them?

Comment: Yes, it's possible to have multiple A/B per ID. I'd want the latest timestamp of A & B.

Comment: Try the update.

Comment: I get an error - KeyError: 'A'

Comment: @RobertCalimente ensure the values in category are really A/B. What gives `df['Category'].unique()`? Please try not to apply blindly a solution but think of what could be different between your example and the real dataset.

Comment: dtype for this field is object. Does that change anything? A/B do exist in the category field that is why I am confused on the KeyError I received

Comment: Can you provide the explicit output of `df['Category'].unique()`?

Comment: array(['A', 'B', 'C',
       'D', 'E', 'F',
       'G'], dtype=object)

Comment: @Robert then I don't know… doesn't make sense. Please provide a DataFrame constructor for you minimal example to be sure we're running the same thing. Works well for me…

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution, based on [`pandas.DataFrame.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html):

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
g = df.groupby('ID')
(g.max()['Date'].sub(g.min()['Date']).dt.total_seconds().div(3600)
 [g['ID'].count().ne(1)].reset_index())
```

Output:

```
   ID  time_diff
0   1       24.0
1   3       24.0
```